# How to render sub block template from another block in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I am learning Wagtail and Django. And I got an issue with the following code.

Main goal is to have separate block templates for carousel items and carousel itself. When I start this code in Wagtail with added carousel items, I see that block template `carousel_main.html` was parsed by Wagtail but block template `carousel_item.html` was not. Most probably I am doing something wrong but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```py
    class CarouselBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
        image = ImageChooserBlock()
        text = blocks.RichTextBlock(blank=True)

        class Meta:
            template = 'carousel_item.html'

    class Carousel(blocks.StructBlock):
        carousel = blocks.ListBlock(CarouselBlock(),blank = True)

        class Meta:
            template = 'carousel_main.html'

    class HomePage(Page):
        carousel_field = StreamField(
            [
                ('carousel',Carousel()),

            ],blank = True
        )

        content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
            StreamFieldPanel('carousel_field')
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, have you already created `carousel_main.html` and `carousel_item.html` at the top of your `templates` directory? (You can place it under the top of your `home/templates` if you'd like.)

If you're still seeing the welcome page when you use `manage.py runserver`, you have to change the contents of your `home_page.html` template as described in the [Wagtail tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/2.7/getting_started/tutorial.html).

Second, have you already used the `include_block` template tag in `home_page.html` and `carousel_main.html`? There are step-by-step instructions on how to use it in the [Wagtail docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/2.7/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering).

Other than that, you're off to a great start.